# dijit Form toJson returns empty object for dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: json, dojo, dijit.form

Running the following code:

```
dojo.toJson(formSearch.attr("value"));
```

Appears to not serialize the value of `dijit.form.DateTextBox` controls.  Looking in Firebug, I can see that `formSearch.attr("value"))` returns the appropriate DOM object that contains the value that the control is set to, but when I try to serialize it, I get something like:

```
{"startDate":{}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute of a `dijit.form.DateTextBox` is of type Date.  This is useful to manipulate Dates from JavaScript, but by default there is no serializer for Dates to JSON.  If you wish to get the value of the widget for serialization, use `dijit.form.DateTextBox.serialize()`, which will give you the value as a string.

If you use the `DateTextBox` in a  or a `dijit.form.Form`, the serialization should happen for you on submit.

Comment: You are right that it is serialized on the form submit, but I wanted to xhr POST as JSON because I was having issues with other components and their values (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908121/value-of-dojox-checkedmultiselect-not-being-posted-with-dojo-xhrpost).  But this makes sense... So thanks for the answer.